# Gamma random variable multiplied with a negative constant

Tags: gamma-distribution

If X has a gamma distribution with shape parameter a and rate parameter b, then kX with also be gamma-distributed with rate parameter $\frac{b}{k}$. But this is only true if k is a positive constant.

What if k is a negative constant? Will it then just be equal to the cdf of a gamma-distribution with a positive k, but with a minus in front?

Comment: What exactly are you asking? cdf won't remain a cdf if a put a minus sign in front.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.